# Accessing Windows Form class member functions from outside

Tags: windows, forms, c++-cli

I have a Windows Form C++  application. In it I have a member that writes log ("WriteLog" entries for various events. 
(in public ref class Form1:)
    public: Void WriteLog(System::Int32, System::Int32, System::String^);

Now I created a separate class, where I want to use the WriteLog function (eg. during the construction, to write into the log that the object got created). But I cant access the function. I dont know how to get to the Form1 object, it doesnt seem to have an object name. There is no 
   formname= gcnew Form. 
The only thing I found was 
   "Application::Run(gcnew Form1());"

I would expect to be able to call the Writelog like 
   formname->WriteLog(1,1,"test")

I totally get the concept of encapsulation, outlined below. But I want to access the member function of the Form class
[Referencing Windows Form elements in other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099938/referencing-windows-form-elements-in-other-classes)

Comment: How many loggers do you want to create?  Most programmers are happy with one, so they declare their logger `static`.  So now it is simple, you use Form1::WriteLog(...);  Next insight is that the logger doesn't have anything to do with a Form object, so they declare it separately.  Solves a lot of circular dependency problems.  Next insight is that logging is already a built-in feature in .NET, so they use Trace::WriteLine(...);

Answer (score -1):

3 options: 
1) Make WriteLog and all involved members a static member function of Form1. Then call Writelog without an object.

2) Create a separate Writelog object outside of Form1 (cleaner)

3) use built in Write function Trace::WriteLine

I chose the first since I had already the code written that way, and Writelog also updates Form textboxes at the same time. (I know, also not clean). It would be more work to rewrite.
Thanks Hans P, you said it all.